# summernote textarea with attribute required does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, required, summernote

I am using the WYSIWYG Editor [summernote](http://summernote.org/).

I have a textarea

```html
<textarea name="data[Text][text]" rows="3" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" cols="30" id="TextText" required="required"></textarea>
```

and a javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#TextText').summernote({
    height: 250,
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', ]],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ]
  });
});
```

As you can see the the textarea has the attribute required, but after I apply the summernote to the textarea, submitting an empty form throws a javascript message in chrome :

> An invalid form control with name='data[Text][text]' is not focusable.

Firefox does not throw any error but also doesn't indicate that the input is required.

How can I force summernote to keep the required attribute?

Answer (score 12):

I cannot found doc for adding attribute `required` but the easiest way is to add event to your form and check if editor `isEmpty` and don't forget to remove `required` attribute from your textarea

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#TextText').summernote({
    height: 250,
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', ]],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ]
  });
});

$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  
  if($('#TextText').summernote('isEmpty')) {
    console.log('contents is empty, fill it!');

    // cancel submit
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    // do action
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.7/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.7/summernote.js"></script>

<form action="/action_page.php" id="myForm">
  <textarea name="data[Text][text]" rows="3" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" cols="30" id="TextText"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```